# React native Flatlist data does't clear even data array is clean

Tags: react-native-flatlist

I wrote an application to show a large data with FlatList but when I use the application the Flatlist is not clear data out while the data array is empty.

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { item, otherParam: item.Word1})}>
            <View style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#eee'}}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <DisplayField value={item.Word1} />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <DisplayField value={item.Word2} />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <DisplayField value={item.Word3} />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <DisplayField value={item.Word4} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      };
```

This is a render code

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SearchBar lightTheme placeholder='Enter your word' onChangeText={this.onChangeTextDelayed} />
        <FlatList style={styles.listContainer}
      data={this.state.data}
      extraData={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.Word1}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
        <View
          style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#CED0CE' }}
          />
      )}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

This is a data retrieving method

```
retriveData = (msg) => {
      if(msg === '') {
        this.setState({data:[]});
        return;
      }

      let limStatement = '';
      let sqlStatement = "SELECT Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4 FROM MyTable WHERE Word1 LIKE '%" + msg + "%' ORDER BY lower(Word2)";
      db.runQuery(sqlStatement).then(rows => { this.setState({ data: rows }) });
  }
```

So when I type for search in textbox Flatlist is showing data properly but when I remove search text it will go to this.setState({data:[]}) to clear state's data out but it happened just some row that not gone,
Example the list show

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
.
.
.
```

when I clear the search out, it seems like.

```
B
B
D
D
E
E
F
F
G
G
G
```

It happens when I scrolling down to far.

Any idea for this?